# How do the stack, heap and stack frame conceptually map to c# constructs?

Tags: c#, heap-memory, stack-frame

How do the stack, heap and stack frame conceptually map to c# constructs? How are the they all related?

Comment: What's a frame (here) and in general, what do you mean? Hardly looks like a real question.

Comment: I assume he means a stack frame

Comment: Very fuzzy question, Janie. Which constructs did you have in mind? Gotta downvote this one, at least until you clear it up.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to make some assumptions about your question:

the .NET call stack (and info for individual frames) are directly accessible via the StackFrame and StackTrace classes in System.Diagnostics.

in .NET, the garbage collector manages "heap" allocations. There are 3 generations of objects, the oldest living in generation 2 at the bottom of the heap. generation 0 is where new objects get allocated from. In addition, large objects are allocated in a separate section.